# Jest doesn't clear old test results

Tags: javascript, jestjs

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "test": "jest --watch",
}
```

then I ran `npm test` in the terminal, the problem I have is, everytime I modified the content of the test file, jest will show old test results in the terminal plus the changed test results, the old test results just keep accumulating up show took up the most portion of the terminal, which is really annoying.
Even I tried `jest --clearCache`, it still showed old test results, so how do I make jest to only display the relevent test content?

Comment: Not an Answer, but  if using VSCode, I recommend you don't use the terminal, and install the Jest-Test-Explorer instead. That will let you easily run all tests, single tests or debug tests without needing to muck with the config.

Comment: If I understand right, I think you are talking about the terminal logs? Ctrl+L / Ctrl+Shift+K should clear the terminal (I think, I avoid the terminal as much as I can)

Comment: Also, are you running `npm test` or `npm run test`. You need the later to run scripts from your package file.